# How detect screen rotation locked in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

How to find screen rotation locked off in windows phone and I'll try to post something legible through my seething anger.

I've seen a couple of posts on here on how to check if the screen rotation is locked off, but none of it has been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `AutoRotationPreferences` property which you can set the orientation of the monitor.

```
private void LockOrientationChange()
{
DisplayProperties.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayProperties.CurrentOrientation;
} 

private void UnlockOrientationChange()
{
DisplayProperties.AutoRotationPreferences =              
         DisplayOrientations.Landscape | 
        DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped | 
        DisplayOrientations.Portrait | 
        DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped;
}
```

See this posts for more:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implementing_Orientation_Lock_In_Windows_Phone

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0e5daccd-2978-4c12-bccf-8b5b4449e94e/lock-the-page-orientation?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: if screen rotation lock on or off these method  **LockOrientationChange()** and **UnlockOrientationChange()** return same result in both cases

Comment: @user3244180 you mean in both cases?